# Creating an event triggering class that can add, trigger and unsubscribe from events

Tags: javascript

I am working on this event emitter javascript problem, can someone help me understand how I would be able to implement release() without passing any arguments to it?

The below code should be able to add events to an array based on type. Trigger events by type while accepting with an arbitrary number of arguments, and release (unsubscribe) events using a reference, simply by calling `sub.release()`.

This is what I have implemented so far, I appreciate any feedback:
https://jsfiddle.net/280toksn/1/

```
class Emitter {
    constructor() {
        this.events = {};
    }
    
    subscribe = (type, fn) => {
        if(this.events[type] === undefined) {
            this.events[type] = [];
        }
        
        this.events[type].push(fn);
        
        return this;
    }
    
    emit = (type,...args) => {
        for(let i=0; i < this.events[type].length; i++) {
            this.events[type][i](...args);
        }
    }
    
    release = () => {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `release` method shouldn't be an instance method of the `Emitter` class, and the `subscribe` method shouldn't return the `Emitter` instance. Each call to `subscribe` should return a different object which has the `release` method.

In JS it's probably fine to just create a plain object to return here but you could also create a separate `Subscription` class if you want. Here is an example with a plain object.

Additionally, I switched it to use a `Set` for the events because it makes things a lot easier.

```
class Emitter {
    constructor() {
        this.events = {};
    }
    
    subscribe = (type, fn) => {
        if(this.events[type] === undefined) {
            this.events[type] = new Set();
        }
        
        this.events[type].add(fn);
        
        return {
            release: () => {
                this.events[type].delete(fn);
            }
        };
    }
    
    emit = (type,...args) => {
        if (this.events[type] === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        [...this.events[type]].forEach(sub => sub(...args));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Chris Rollins, really helpful. Can you elaborate why using a Set here makes things a lot easier? what considerations go in to deciding if a Set or a different data structure is better?

Comment: When removing something from a `Set` you don't have to worry about creating a "hole" so to speak. If you are using an array, removing an item leaves `undefined` at that location, so then you need to move the other items to fill it in, or check for those holes when you search. Either way it's more code to write which is annoying and more opportunities for bugs. Also, in this case I wasn't too worried about the performance difference because I don't imagine you would be scaling this up to a huge number of subscriptions, but actually the `Set` should perform better and that's a nice bonus.

Comment: As for performance, `Set` and `Map` are better when you need to search for a particular item or you need to remove things from arbitrary locations. They are usually implemented as some kind of tree if they are ordered, or a hashtable if they are unordered. In both cases you can insert and remove without having to move every other item.
Arrays are best when you never have to search (always know the index you need).

Comment: Another consideration here is whether you want to allow the same function reference to be registered more than once. In a `Set` every value is unique, so you can't add the same reference more than once. Note that you can add identical functions because it's a reference type.
It seems like you wouldn't intentionally add the same function multiple times so it's probably a benefit, but I suppose that could be debatable.
Anyway, when you're considering using a `Set` this uniqueness is one of the primary considerations. It can be a huge benefit in some cases but in other cases it might not be.